# AngularJS - Reset form input field from Factory method

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to reset my form on submission from my Factory?  I am currently resetting it inline, but would like to make it cleaner.  If not, what would be a better way to do it?

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ToDoController', function($scope, todos){
    $scope.todos = todos;
});

app.factory('todos', function(){
    var todos = {};

    todos.list = [];

    todos.addTodo = function(todo){
        todos.list.push({
            task:todo,
            completed: false
        });
    }    
    return todos;
})

app.directive('todo', function(){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl:'templates/todos.html',
        controller:'ToDoController'
    }
})
```

// template

```
<form name="todoForm" novalidate class="text-center">
  <input type="text" ng-model="input">

<!-- it is being reset on the line below  after ngClick-->
            <button ng-click="todos.addTodo(input); input='';" class="btn" type="submit" ng-disabled="!input">Submit</button>
    </form
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure:

```
app.controller('ToDoController', function($scope, todos){
    $scope.addTodo = function() {
        todos.addTodo($scope.input);
        $scope.input = '';
    };
});
```

and in the view:

```
<button ng-click="addTodo()" ...
```

Comment: I could do that, but I am trying to keep my controller as lean as possible.

Comment: Perhaps there is an angular directive I could use in the markup?

Comment: The controller's job is to expose the model and react to events from the view. The code has to be somewhere. Better in the controller than in the view. What's the point of having controllers if you don't want to put any code inside?

Comment: Can I access the form field from the factory?  If I put the reset in the controller it will not be reusable.

Comment: A controller is not supposed to be reusable. It's supposed to implement the logic needed by a specific template. The template and the controller go hand in hand.

Comment: Right.  I'm saying if I can put the reset code in the factory, it will be reusable.

Comment: No, it won't. It's just the inverse, since your service, which is usable from any other component, would then contain logic that is specific to a particular view.